# DRF all features have positive contribution to SHAP values except one

Tags: python, h2o, shapley-value

I have trained a DRF model using h2o and the shap summary plot came out like this.

Why aren't feature contributions centered? It seems weird that one feature contributes negatively and all the others positively.

How should I interpret this? Is this an indication of a problem in my data?

[image]